# Is there a term for this property of operations/relationships?

Tags: terminology

Say $h$ is related to $g$ in some way, denote this by $h:R:g$. Say we also have *some* kind of operation that we can perform on both $h$ and $g$. Denote this operation by $*$. The relation, $R$, is such that:

$$hRg \implies h*x :R: g*x$$

For example, if $h, g, x \in \mathbb{Z}$, the relation $~\geq~$ with the operation $[\text{multiplication}]$ does not have this property, because one could multiply by $-1$. It *would* if $h, g, x \in \mathbb{Z}^+$. Equality has this property with *any* operation (as does any equivalence relation, I think).

Is there a name for this property?

---

I understand this is somewhat abstract, and I may be ignorant of a whole slew of terminology. To put this in some context, this question came from my having to prove to myself that, if $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$, then $g*H*g^{-1} = H ~~\forall g \in G$ (where $*$ in this case is the group operation). We certainly know $g*H*g^{-1} \subseteq H$. Group-operating by $g$ on the right and $g^{-1}$ on the left, *assuming $(\subseteq, *)$ has this property*, would show $H \subseteq g^{-1}*H*g = g*H*g^{-1}$.

(Indeed, $(\subseteq, *)$ has this property)

Comment: In the motivating example, it's somewhat hard to be certain what $\ast$ refers to, since that notation isn't used anywhere else in that example. Is it "conjugation by $g$ (or $g^{-1}$)" ? So your assertion that "$(\subseteq, \ast)$ has this property" is the claim that $H \subseteq K \implies g^{-1}Hg \subseteq g^{-1}Kg$ ? (As an aside, it may be better to call your operation $f$ or something, so you can write $f(h) : R : f(g)$ above; while $\ast$ is OK, I'm not sure what $x$ has to do with anything)

Comment: @pjs36 Check out my edit (it was made 3-seconds after your comment, haha). Does this make more sense? (You're right about not-using-this-notation anywhere else. I put it into my group example to be more explicit.)

Comment: Yes, that does help, I think. I guess in the example at least, that $h, g$ belong to a set $S$ on which a relation $R$ is defined, and that you have a group acting on $S$ (at first, I thought all of $h, g$, and $x$ would be coming from $S$, but that's not the case).